# In Matthew 24:38

Tags: prophecy, eschatology, marriage, olivet-discourse

In Matthew 24:38 What is the difference between marrying and giving in marriage in this passage.

It appears that the passage is talking about two types of marriages.

> Matt 24:38 - For as in those days before the flood, they were eating
> and drinking, marrying and giving in marriage, until that day Noah
> entered into the ark

Comment: Pleonasm is a common ancient linguistic feature of redundancy in phrases or saying. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/43399/origin-of-pleonastic-phrasology-in-the-bible

Comment: Matt. 22:30; 24:38; Mk. 12:25; Lk. 17:27; 20:35 Are the references for this case.

Comment: Men marry. Women are given in marriage. Men take the initiative and approach a family. The family responds (if they and the woman are so inclined) and they 'give' the woman to the man. The man 'takes' the woman. (This, all, in civilised God-fearing societies, of course.)

Comment: That may sound foreign to us, but that was the terms of the 1st century.

Comment: @Betho'sAnother reference in the N.T. is 1 Corinthians 7:38. "He that giveth her in marriage..."  Note the modern ceremony:  "Who giveth this woman  to be married to this man?" (Her mother and I.)  To the questioner, these are NOT two types of marriage. But the same one.

Answer (score 4):

Just as "eating and drinking" are two parts of the one act of partaking of a meal, so "marrying and giving in marriage" are two parts of the one ceremony of marriage.

That is, to create a marriage -

- the bridegroom marries the bride
- the parents of the bride give her in marriage

Both acts are required (in Bible times at least) to create a marriage.  We see the same expression elsewhere such as Gen 29:26, Josh 15:16, Judges 1:12, 3:6, 21;1, 7, 1 Sam 17:25, 18:17, Ezra 9:12, Neh 10:30, Neh 13:25, Dan 11:17, Matt 22:30, Mark 12:25, Luke 17:27, 20:35, 1 Cor 7:38, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "marrying and giving in marriage" in MT 24:38 (KJV, et al.) is translated from the words seen in several early-to-mid-fourth (4th) century CE Greek language biblical manuscripts, namely *Sinaiticus* (01), *Vaticanus* (03), *Bezae Cantabrigiensis* (05), and *Washingtonianus* (032, aka "Freer Gospels").

The Greek word γαμουντες (*gamountes*, marrying) is in all of the above named manuscripts, and also in all reputable Greek New Testaments (GNTs). But there are variations in spelling (variant spellings) of the Greek word translated as "giving in marriage"; specifically:

```
1: codices 01 and 05 spell that word γαμιζοντες, as explained above;
2: codex 03 spells that word γαμισκοντες (*gamiskontes*), and
3: codex 032 spells it εκγαμισκοντες (*ekgamikontes*).
```

Nevertheless, each of those variant spellings were translated into English as "giving in marriage," even though some GNTs spell the word the same as 01 and 05, but others as 032.

Also, both of the Greek words for "marrying" and "giving in marriage" are masculine nouns. For this reason, "marrying and giving in marriage" is better read as **men marrying wives and men getting engaged to marry wives**.